# save data into remote database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I need to store information fill-up by user from mobile end to the remote server. For example I have write below code for login/registration. I have tried this but not getting any kind of data store in server. I doubted that may be my PHP script was wrong.

MainActivity.Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView name, email, number;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void send(View v) {

    new Send().execute();

}

class Send extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Long> {

    protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String Name = name.getText().toString();
        String Email = email.getText().toString();
        String Number = number.getText().toString();

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://xxx.000webhostapp.com/phpcode.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", Name));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", Email));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Number", Number));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

        }
    }
}
```

A new record is created to test it. It worked so far, it creates new entries.

php script:

```
<?php

define('hostname', 'localhost');
define('user', 'xxx_username');
define('passwort', 'xxx');
define('databaseName', 'xxx_name');

$conn = mysqli_connect(hostname, user, passwort, databaseName);

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " .$conn->connect_error);
}


$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Number = $_POST['Number'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO demotable (Name, Email, Number) VALUES ('{$Name}','{$Email}','{$Number}')";

if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record created";
} else {
    echo "Error: ".$sql. $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
 "2" should be removed I guess.

Comment: Test with a REST Client such POSTMAN or ARC that is a Chrome App and see if its may be a server error

Comment: Review your phpcode.php. I think something is wrong with phpcode.php.

Comment: Is ArrayList not making any difference there?just see the code once..arraylist of size 2?

Comment: Where is your send() method called?

Comment: @R.R.M it's a onClick action, probably

Comment: You really should print something out in the catch block... You probably have an exception that's ignored

Comment: I added the php code, but I think this side works so far

Comment: @R.R.M send method is an onClick as cricket_007 said

Comment: Just follow this nice tutorial written for you especially and figure-out your self.https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform a UI operation in **doInBackground()** hence it results in a exception before even making a network call. UI Operations can only be performed in **onPreExecute()** and **onPostExecute()**. Whereas the network calls are to be performed in just **doInBackground()**. Try this code

```
class Send extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Long> {
String Name,Email,Number;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    Name = name.getText().toString();
    Email = email.getText().toString();
    Number = number.getText().toString();
}
@Override
protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://affe.000webhostapp.com/phpcode.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", Name));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", Email));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Number", Integer.toString(Number)));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    return null;

}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

    }
}
```

Comment: 'name', 'email' and 'number' cannot be resolved, can I stil define them as a TextView?

Comment: You might have missed out on something. Since the way you have defined it in your activity, this error shouldn't come up.

Comment: Yes, I messed something up, sorry! 
But unfortunately I still don't get an entry for my textfields with your improvements

Comment: It still doesn't send any data to the database. I linked the onClick in the xml layout with my send() method. I thought it would work as well, so maybe the transmission could be wrong?

Comment: How did you mean that dissent?

Comment: Postman is an desktop app that allows you to make HTTP request. Hit your url with a specific data and check if your PHP code is working properly